# How can I create one function that will be called by all three buttons instead of function for each different button?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How can I create one function that will be called by all three buttons instead of function for each different button?

```
function input1()
{window.alert("You selected option 1!");}

function input2() {window.alert("You selected option 2!");}

function input3() {window.alert("You selected option 3!");}

<h1>Select a button</h1>

<form name="optionsForm" action="">

<input type="button" name="1" value="Option 1" onclick="input1()" />
<input type="button" name="2" value="Option 2" onclick="input2()" />
<input type="button" name="3" value="Option 3" onclick="input3()" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass text you need to alert to function as a parameter, like this:

```
function inputAlert(optionName) {window.alert('Selected '+optionName);} 

<input type="button" name="1" value="Option 1" onclick="inputAlert('Option 1')" />
<input type="button" name="2" value="Option 2" onclick="inputAlert('Option 2')" />
<input type="button" name="3" value="Option 3" onclick="inputAlert('Option 3')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function input(val) {window.alert("You selected option "+val+"!");}

<h1>Select a button</h1>

<form name="optionsForm" action="">

<input type="button" name="1" value="Option 1" onclick="input(1)" />
<input type="button" name="2" value="Option 2" onclick="input(2)" />
<input type="button" name="3" value="Option 3" onclick="input(3)" />

</form>
```

Comment: You can help people by placing the green tick to an answer, if you accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use jQuery and put the  same class on each button. Thus with a selector you will have one function for all 3 buttons.

It should look something like:

```
<input class="myclass" type="button" name="1" value="Option 1"/>
<input class="myclass" type="button" name="2" value="Option 2"/>
<input class="myclass" type="button" name="3" value="Option 3"/>
```

and have some jquery code like:

```
$('.myclass').click(function(){
// my code comes here
alert($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bogdan Emil. I am new with JavaScript and your sample will be an introduction to me to JQuery.